# как реализовать недетерминированный конечный автомат?

Tags: javascript

Задание: написать функцию, которая выполняет один цикл работы недетермированного конечного автомата и процедуру распознавания слов недетерминированным конечным автоматом.

Есть псевдокод, который определяет, допускает ли НКА данное слово или нет.

Не понимаю, как его применить к представленной схеме на рисунке.

1. R-множество достижимых состояний,
2. w-слово,
3. T-множество допускающих состояний автомата,
4. δ — функция переходов,
5. Σ — алфавит,
6. Q — множество состояний автомата,
7. s — начальное состояние автомата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var states = {
    q0:{
        name: 'q0',
        isFinish: false,
        next: {
            'a': 'q3',
            'a': 'q6',
            'a': 'q5'
        }
    },

    q1: {
        name: 'q1',
        isFinish: false,
        next: {
            'a': 'q5',
            'a': 'q6'
        }
    },

    q3: {
      name: 'q3',
      isFinish: true,
      next: {
          'b':'q4'
      }
    },

    q4: {
        name: 'q4',
        isFinish: true,
        next: {
            'b': 'q4'
        }
    },

    q5: {
        name: 'q5',
        isFinish: false,
        next: {
            'b': 'q1'
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Запустить КА" onclick="start()">
```

Comment: не, описание состояний для детерминированного автомата тут не подойдет :)

Comment: добавь описание специальных обозначений из псевдокода, то есть что такое эти сигмы, лямбды и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy, R-множество достижимых состояний, w-слово, T-множество допускающих состояний автомата,  δ — функция переходов,  Σ — алфавит, Q — множество состояний автомата, s — начальное состояние автомата

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С недетерминированным автоматом, все несколько сложнее.

Фактически, автомат может находиться сразу в нескольких состояниях, поэтому нужно проверять сразу все возможный переходы.

Если немного расписать указанный псевдокод, получится так:

1. Устанавливаем начальное состояние
2. Для каждого символа из строки

   1. Устанавливаем доступные состояния в пустое множество
   2. Идем по всем переходам из предыдущего состояния
   3. Если переход возможен сохраняем доступное состояние
3. Проверяем что конечное множество переходов пересекается со множеством конечных состояний.

Под этот алгоритм нужно немного изменить хранение состояний: теперь вместо одного значения по ключу в объекте `next`, будет хранится массив.

```
q0:{
    name: 'q0',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {'a': ['q3', 'q6', 'q5']}
}
```

Для работы с множествами можно воспользоваться [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Функция перехода может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
function step(nexts, symbol) {
  return [
    ...new Set( // отбираем только уникальные имена состояния
      [].concat( // собираем все в один большой список
        ...nexts.filter(c => c[symbol]) // отбираем состояния куда можем перейти по символу
        .map(c => c[symbol]) // получаем списки возможных переходов
      )
    )
  ].map(c => states[c]) // по имени состояний получаем сами состояния
}
```

На входе получаем список всех возможных переходов, на выходе - список возможных переходов по указанному символу.

После прохождения всей цепочки смотрим список состояний в которых мы можем находиться, и если есть хотя бы одно конечное состояние - цепочка распознана.

Пример реализации:

```js
var states = {
  q0: {
    name: 'q0',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
      'a': ['q3', 'q6', 'q5']
    }
  },

  q1: {
    name: 'q1',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
      'a': ['q5', 'q6']
    }
  },

  q3: {
    name: 'q3',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
      'b': ['q4']
    }
  },

  q4: {
    name: 'q4',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
      'b': ['q4']
    }
  },

  q5: {
    name: 'q5',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
      'b': ['q1']
    }
  },
  q6: {
    name: 'q6',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {}
  }
};

function step(nexts, symbol) {
  return [
    ...new Set( // отбираем только уникальные имена состояния
      [].concat( // собираем все в один большой список
        ...nexts.filter(c => c[symbol]) // отбираем состояния куда можем перейти по символу
        .map(c => c[symbol]) // получаем списки возможных переходов
      )
    )
  ].map(c => states[c]) // по имени состояний получаем сами состояния
}

function start(w) {
  var current = [states.q0];
  for (var i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    current = step(current.map(c => c.next), w[i]);
  }
  var terminated = current.filter(c => c.isFinish); // получаем список конечных состояний из текущего списка, если есть хотя бы одно конечное состояние - цепочка распознаная
  console.log(terminated.length > 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Запустить КА" onclick="start('ababa')">
```

Comment: `[...new Set]` - это шедевр =) Отстаю я с этой поддержкой старья :(